# Laravel getting data from other table in view when you know the id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table "reviews" with a column named "from_user". So basically the user who placed the review. In this column the users's id is stored from the users table. Is it possible to find out the users name in my view?

This is what it looks like now:

```
 @foreach($authUser->reviews as $review)
   <p>{{ $review->body }} - {{$review->from_user }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

So this code now obviously displays the id of the user.

This is what my users table looks like:

> ID | NAME | USERNAME | ...

This is what my reviews table looks like:

> ID | from_user | on_user | body

so the from_user from my reviews table equals the ID of my users table

So my question is is it possible to access my username in my foreach loop in my view?

I am fairly new to laravel so any help is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

### EDIT: User Model

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, Messagable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'straat', 'postcode', 'plaats', 'provincie', 'role', 'specialisatie'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
    }

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

### EDIT2 my Review model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $table = 'reviews';

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide user model?

Comment: @xdevnull Yes, checkout edited OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

In your `review model` you need to tell the relation what foreign key to use. By default it add `relationName_id`.

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the
>   name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with
>   _id. However, if the foreign key on the Phone model is not user_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo
>   method. [**#Source**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $table = 'reviews';

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'from_user');
    }
}
```

And in your view

```
@foreach($authUser->reviews as $review)
   <p>{{ $review->body }} - {{ $review->user->name }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: I think I have the relationship checkout edited OP I added my User model

Comment: I've applied the relation for ```Review``` model. read **class name**.

Comment: Could you checkout my edited OP I added my User & Review model is my realtionship correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's quite simple :)